# Exception error when String equals NULL

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, null

I'm trying to set some default settings when the app is first launched. I try and detect when the String equals null but it keeps throwing an exception error, any ideas?

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    String isFirstRun = settings["firstrun"] as string;

    if (isFirstRun == null)
    {
        settings["firstrun"] = "no";
        settings["defaultLocation"] = "Dulles, VA";
        settings["defaultTest"] = "Speed Test";
        settings.Save();
    }
}
```

The exception error is:

> MyConnection.DLL!MyConnection.App.RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e) Line 103    C#

Comment: First check if `settings["firstrun"]` is `null` before you try to cast it to string. Even better, don't cast it at all...

Comment: "but it keeps throwing an exception error" - precisely what exception?

Comment: I've removed tags from question's title - please note than in most cases questions [shouldn't include tag in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Updated opening question with edits

Comment: @Liel I performed a check before casting it, a bit messy I'm sure but it works and it's been annoying me for a good hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first Add key to Dictionary (IS) before you use it - check if IS contains the key for the first run:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

if (!settings.Contains("firstrun"))
{
    settings.Add("firstrun", "no");
    settings.Add("defaultLocation", "Dulles, VA");
    settings.Add("defaultTest", "Speed Test");
    settings.Save();
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code above (see my opening question edits), with no luck. I'm doing this all in the App.cs, is that causing an issue?

Comment: No idea why this didn't work the first time I tried it!! But thank you as it was, of course, the correct solution

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer I hope you have found solution. This code should work when App is run for the very first run (later you should replace those `Add` with `[""]` (modification of key value). As for checking you can also try to us [IsApplicationPreserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx) - but you should be aware that it will also returne false from Tombstone mode.